# create an alert with js by using php

Tags: javascript, php

When I am using JS with PHP i meet a problem

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("my alert");</script>';
                        header('Location: /toto.com/');
```

The JS alert isn't working

Thank you for your help

Comment: Tip: Use Ajax in such cases.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve here. Display an alert then redirect to another page? At the moment you can't send a header after you've already output something. PHP should tell you headers have already been sent (I think its E_WARNING)

Comment: it's in a form.
I want to alert the member that sth is ok and after redirect on an other page.
Ajax seems inapropriate since everything is in PHP exept this tiny part of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Javascript` is client side language and `PHP` is server side language so it is executed before your client side code will get executed. Now you are doing like this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("my alert");</script>';
header('Location: /toto.com/');
```

**Fault**

Your PHP script is putting `HTML` block first and then redirecting it to the location you have mentioned in your `header()` without giving any chance to your `script` to be executed.

**Code should be like this**

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("my alert"); window.location.href="/toto.com/";</script>';
```

This should work...

Comment: I am glad this worked @GromainGillier, just accept this answer as solved, so that it will help others too :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
           window.alert('Succesfully Updated')
           window.location.href='http://localhost/test1.php';
       </SCRIPT>");
```

Hope this will work for you..

Comment: @SanjayChaudhari this won't work unless you get `headers already sent` `warning`

Comment: Why are you writing HTML 3.2 this century?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working.. only the `header('Location: /toto.com/');` causing the problem.

```
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("my alert");</script>';
  //header('Location: /toto.com/');
```

Run the code by commenting the redirection, then you can see the alert message.